# Time Duration in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Trying to figure out time formatting is absolutely killing me.

When I press a button I collect a start time using:

```
StartTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh.mm.ss.tt")
```

Then when the calculation is done I have:

```
EndTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh.mm.ss.tt")
```

What I would like to do is to:

```
TotalTime = EndTime - StartTime
```

But to print the time using the format; "?# Hours, ## Minutes, & ## Seconds"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I probably wouldn't use the `ToString()` function on the StartTime and EndTime variables, since that turns them into strings.

Try this:

```
Dim StartTime as DateTime = DateTime.Now

'' Do Stuff

Dim EndTime As DateTime = DateTime.Now

Dim TotalTime As TimeSpan = EndTime - StartTime

Me.Text = TotalTime.ToString("hh':'mm':'ss")
```

Of course, you can skip the TotalTime variable and just calculate it in place:

```
Me.Text = (EndTime - StartTime).ToString("hh':'mm':'ss")
```

Comment: You both answered the question, or at least got me thinking about a better solution. I completely forgot that I had datetime.now.tostring .... I posted what I ended up going with above under the *edit

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate durations, you must not use the string type. Use directly the DateTime variables (that is, `DateTime.Now`). You should get a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) object when subtracting.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim TotalTime As TimeSpan = EndTime - StartTime
Console.WriteLine( _
    "{0:#0} Hours, {1:00} Minutes, & {2:00} Seconds", _
    Math.Truncate(TotalTime.TotalHours), _
    TotalTime.Minutes, _
    TotalTime.Seconds _
)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

LarsTech answer got me thinking about a better solution. I completely forgot that I had datetime.now.tostring. What I ended up going is:

```
timenow = DateTime.Now
start = DateTime.Now

Dim totaltime As TimeSpan = (timenow - start)
xlWorkSheet201.Cells(3, 9) = "Total Test Time: " & Format(totaltime.Hours, "#0") & " Hours, " & Format(totaltime.Minutes, "#0") & "Minutes, & " & Format(totaltime.Seconds, "00") & "Seconds."
```